# Resolution of the pushforward of a vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory

Let $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ be a subvariety of a compact Kahler manifold. Assume that $Z$ can be realize as the zero locus of a section $s$ of a holomorphic vector bundle $E\to X$ of rank $r$. The Koszul complex
$$\Lambda^rE^*\to \Lambda^{r-1}E^*\to ...\to E^*\to \mathcal{O}(X)\to i_*\mathcal{O}(Z)\to 0$$
gives a resolution of $i_*\mathcal{O}(Z)$ by vector bundles.

Let now $F\to Z$ be a holomorphic vector bundle on $Z$. How can we modify the complex above to obtain a resolution of $i_*F$ ?

Comment: Apply the [projection formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_formula).

Comment: @Z.M I guess that in your analogy $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{O}(Z)$ for me, but what would be $\mathcal{E}$ ? I would be grateful if you could develop a little

Comment: If $F$ extends to a holomorphic vector bundle $G$ on $X$, then you want to tensor each term with $G$ to obtain a resolution of $i_* F=( i_* \mathcal O(Z)) \otimes G$. If not, then I don't think Z. M's idea will help.

Comment: @WillSawin I indeed did not assume that $F$ comes from a restriction of a bundle on $X$

Comment: Probably there is no way to do it by modifying the Koszul complex and you need to use a different method (e.g. twisting by ample line bundles and taking global sections)